# change map size on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I set it up so when a user clicks the submit button, the map will resize itself to fit directions as it is on yelp maps when finding directions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without much information in your question, just add a style modification in your map direction handler.  In it's simplest form:  But without knowing more about your particular setup, I can't do much more.

HTML:

```
<FORM onSubmit="findDirections()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function findDirections() {
    // Change map width
    document.getElementsById("directions_map").style.width = "600px";

    // Do google maps lookup, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to set center and zoom of map to have direction fit in such a view? If so, you can obtain points of this direction, add them to create `LatLngBounds` (using the `extend` method) and use  `Map.fitBounds` with prepared bounds as parameter.